# FIWARE Orion: Multitenancy and Federation

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I would like to know how can I create tenants in Orion. I understand that you need to inform Orion of the multitenancy by adding the `-multiservice` parameter. However, I do not know what is necessary to create, indeed, a tenant.

From what I have seen in the documentation, my guess is that you just need to add the `Fiware-Service` header in each HTTP request. Therefore, if you send a `updateContext` with a `Fiware-Service=t_01` Orion will automatically create that tenant. **Is this right?**

In addition to this, I also would like to know if multitenancy works correctly (or is planned to work correctly) in the following scenario:
[image]

In other words, is it possible to have several Gateways, each one with an Orion with one or more tenants, and all the Orions of all the Gateways federated to a global Orion in the cloud? Will the tenancy be respected in the global orion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are right: Orion creates tenants "on the fly", the first time a create entity/registry operation in the given tenant is processed.

Regarding the scenario in the picture I understand that you refer to the federation approach described in [this section in the manual](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/federation/index.html), based on notifyContext. Given that Orion includes the `Fiware-Service` header in notifications, it should work.